# access multiple subparsers at once in argparse python

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

How I can access access multiple subparsers at once in argparse python.
also i should pass multiple args also in the same command like above. there can be multiple inputs for a subparsed argument.

```
subparser = parser.add_subparser(dest='action')

create = subparser.add_parser('create')
update = subparser.add_parser('update')

create.add_argument(--name,nargs='*')
update.add_argument(--user,nargs='*')

args = parser.parse_args()

COMMAND : python3 myscript.py create --name "rickey" update --user "alex" "yohan" "jimmy"
```

Comment: Using multiple arguments for a single command/option (I assume you are referring to the `--password` option example given) is explained in the documentation, and probably easy to find. I propose to skip that part, and focus on the first part. Also, since when do accounts have three passwords?

Comment: This is an example only for reference. maybe an other example can be...      
    python3 myscript.py result --name "vicky" score --graduation "80" "90" "95".

Comment: Just want to access multiple arguments at once when I have subparsers also in place.

Comment: Multiple arguments: use the `nargs='*'` or `action='append'` arguments.

Comment: your example isn't clear.  In any case, the `subparsers` mechanism only works once - once a subparser is done, the main parser does not resume parsing.

Comment: don't put code in a comment.

Comment: added the code in question

Comment: what should I do when I have to create and update for users in one command.

Comment: You might experiment with making multiple calls to `parse_known_args`, feeding the leftover arguments from one call to the next.

Comment: A subparser can have more than one argument, just like a "regular" parser.  It might easiest if you define another subparser that takes both the '--name' and '--users' arguments.

Comment: yes, i can. but the problem here is when i use both the parser(create, update) at once, it is giving error.